# react memo comparison function with static return true or false

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I am new to react, specially react hooks. I have a component wrapping in `React.memo` naming `WithMemo`. I pass a function as comparison function without considering the previous or next props value, I return true or false but both returns have the same result : not re-rendering.
can anyone tell me what is the behavior?

here is my code:

```
const WithMemo: FC<{ list: number[] }> = React.memo(({ list }) => {
  console.log('Yes memo', list)
  return <p>hello</p>
}, (prev, nxt) => false)

const MyList: FC<{ list: number[] }> = ({ list }) => {
  console.log('No memo', list)
  return <p>hello</p>
}


function App() {
  const [c, setC] = useState('')
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyList list={[1, 2, 3]} />
      <WithMemo list={[1, 2, 3]} />
      <input type="text" value={c} onChange={e => setC(e.currentTarget.value)} />
      <p>{c}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @Medi shouldn't it be different results? if not why?

Comment: Your component is re-rendering as expected https://jsfiddle.net/fptwmb6k/ unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is a function that returns when the components should be the same, given the props. That said, in your demo you should return true to no re-rendering and if you passfalse it will re-rendering

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const WithMemo = React.memo(
  ({ list }) => {
    console.log("Yes memo", list);
    return <p>hello</p>;
  },
  (prev, nxt) => true
);

const MyList = ({ list }) => {
  console.log("No memo", list);
  return <p>hello</p>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [c, setC] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyList list={[1, 2, 3]} />
      <WithMemo list={[1, 2, 3]} />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={c}
        onChange={(e) => setC(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <p>{c}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Tested here
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-chandrasekhar-m4mhe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: its a test case and it works fine. but for my project i only compare one prop which is a number, but it re-renders.